# Defining plot options once and call them for several subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using several subplots. In these subplots data is plotted using `imshow`. The options I pass to `imshow` are identical for almost all of the subplots. However, they pollute my code due to the length of the options.

The options I use include:

- `extent`
- `cmap`
- `norm`
- `origin`
- `interpolation`

To have a better overview of my code I would like to define the options once and call them for each subplot. What is a pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the options in a dictionary and then unpack them within the function call using the [`**kwargs` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/3005188), as below (example uses `plot` rather than `imshow` but it's the same idea).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

options = {'linewidth':2,
           'color':'red',
           'linestyle':'dashed'}

x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,y, **options)

plt.show()
```

Above I have stored the options in the `options` dictionary and then unpacked them within the plot function call with `ax.plot(x,y, **options)`.